# What request scheduler does my system use? `/sys/block/nvme0n1/queue/scheduler` lists 2

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, scheduler

I've just read the [excellent article on linux block layer](https://lwn.net/Articles/738449/).

I started wondering which of the scheduling algorithms are used in my own computer.

My specific question is: How to interpret the content of `/sys/block/nvme0n1/queue/scheduler`?

```
❯ cat /sys/block/nvme0n1/queue/scheduler 
[none] mq-deadline kyber
```

But as I understood mq-deadline and kyber are alternatives, so which one is actually used? None?

My general question is: How do I check the algorithms used at various places in the linux OS I'm running? Ideal would be some tool that gives you a gist: from cpu scheduling algorithms, to request schedulers, what internal data structures if there are some choices and so on. Numerical details (i.e. max number of inodes) are not interesting. I don't have any real goal, other than satisfy curiosity and find a good learning possibility.

Thanks!

Comment: Active state is in square brackets, i.e. in this case it’s `none`. This a common way for the lists in sysfs in the Linux kernel. If there is a tool, it does basically lot of reads in sysfs and procfs, you even can write a simple shell script for that.

Comment: NVMe does not need a scheduler since there are no heads or command queuing.